# CSS layout error only happens randomly in Chrome on OS X

Tags: css, layout, google-chrome

So this is a strange one which has caused me a lot of head scratching. There seems to be a layout bug on a site I made a while back that only happens occasionally on Chrome for OS X. (See the image below).

I have tried Chrome on Ubuntu and Windows 7, and I can´t reproduce the error there. As well as Firefox, Safari, etc.

The site is available here: [designstudier.no](http://designstudier.no/)

I am really at a loss as what the problem may be. I´m running the same version of Chrome on OSX, Ubuntu and Windows 7, and this has been happening for the last few Chrome versions. There weird part is that it only happens occasionally.

I would appreciate any input, thank you.

[Full res image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkTlS.jpg)
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually fixed itself. It seems that it *might* have been an issue with Chrome which got fixed in a later version. Anyway, Chrome was updated and I can no longer reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can write spesific CSS code for each operating system and and each browser.

http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/